# Why is this$0 field of an inner class not private?

Tags: java

Java inner classes store the reference to the outer instance in a synthetic field:

```
class A {
    class B {}
}

java.util.Arrays.toString(A.B.class.getDeclaredFields())
// [final A A$B.this$0]
```

What I am wondering is why this field isn't generated as private.

It can't be accessed by the programmer without reflection (outside `B`, where `A.this` refers to it).

The obvious guess is that you can write something in `A` (outside `B`) which needs to access it, but I can't think of any such case.

Comment: You should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303833/inner-class-in-java)

Comment: I was about to say "so that this field can be set by the outer class upon creation", but that of course would also work with private fields ...

Comment: @Novy Can you explain why? I don't see anything there I didn't already know.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov The why in my point of view is because in java by default fields, method, and classes are package-private, which means they cannot be accessed from outside of their package. The A$B.this$0 is generated the genarated class is  A$B as a generated field it respect the default.   A$B.this$0 is a reference to your outer this(A.this). So If you are in A (outside B) you already have access the A.this.  I do not know if it is what your are looking for

Comment: I believe I've found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking in the wrong direction. It isn't `A` that needs to access `B.this$0`, but potential inner classes of `B` itself!

If we have

```
class A {
    class B {
        class C {}
    }
}
```

then after desugaring `C` becomes

```
class A$B$C {
    final A$B this$1;

    A$B$C(A$B b) {
        this$1 = b;
    }
}
```

and `A.this` inside `C` has to be accessed as `this$1.this$0`. Alternatively, it could have two fields

```
    final A$B this$1;
    final A this$0;
```

in which case the constructor would contain `this$0 = b.this$0;` (this was actually what I expected before checking).